# How can I use add_library in 'CMakeLists.txt' to include entire files(.cpp,.h etc) in a directory

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-studio-2.3

In my project I am using cpp and .h files they all are in different folders

```
|-src
  |-main
   |-java
   |-cpp
    |-native-lib.cpp
    |-library-1
      |-include
        |-lib11.h
        |-lib12.h
        |-... 
    |-library-2
      |-include
        |-lib21.h
        |-lib22.h
        |-...
```

in current version i  am adding each files into `'CMakeLists.txt'`

```
...

add_library(# Sets the name of the library.
            native-lib

            # Sets the library as a shared library.
            SHARED

            # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).



            src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
            src/main/cpp/library-1/include/lib10.h
            src/main/cpp/library-1/include/lib11.h
            src/main/cpp/library-1/include/lib12.h
            src/main/cpp/library-1/include/lib13.h
            ...

            src/main/cpp/library-2/include/lib21.h
            src/main/cpp/library-2/include/lib22.h
            src/main/cpp/library-2/include/lib23.h
            ...

)
...
```

I tried adding like  below

```
...

add_library(# Sets the name of the library.
            native-lib

            # Sets the library as a shared library.
            SHARED

            # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).



            src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
            src/main/cpp/library-1/include/*.h  #expected result: it  will include all '.h' files in directory, but gradle sync failed

            src/main/cpp/library-2/include/*.h#expected result: it  will include all '.h' files in directory, but gradle sync failed


)
...
```

Any other way to include all files in a folder using `add_library`

after suggestion from Lucky

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

  include_directories(src/main/cpp/library-1/include)
  include_directories(src/main/cpp/library-2/include)



file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.h")
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib


             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).

             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             ${SOURCES}




             )




# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: @André I tried your suggestion, but it is not worked for me

Comment: Thanks @André problem solved by adding `GLOB_RECURSE`

Answer (score 18):

You can generate a list of your source files:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.h")
```

Now the SOURCES variable can be used as a parameter in add_library.

```
add_library(native-lib SHARED ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: this time  linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Can you show the whole file ?

Comment: Added in question.

Comment: Try the following find_library: 
`find_library(log-lib NAMES log)`

Comment: Probably you also have to specify the path: 
`find_library(log-lib NAMES log PATHS *path*)`

Comment: Thank you @Lucky for your time, problem solved by adding `GLOB_RECURSE`